# Centos lxc container won't start on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I am trying to run Centos containers in Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic and also Ubuntu 14.04 trusty. I created the container in several different ways and no matter what it won't start and spits those lines:

```
# lxc-start -n centos1 -F
init: Failed to spawn lxc-sysinit pre-start process: unable to set priority: Permission denied
init: Failed to spawn rcS pre-start process: unable to set priority: Permission denied
init: Failed to spawn rcS post-stop process: unable to set priority: Permission denied
```

I searched here and there and I found some things. I tried adding those lines in the config one by one and all of them:

```
lxc.aa_allow_incomplete = 1
lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

I also tried different ways to create the container:

```
lxc-create -n centos1 -t download -- -d centos --release 6 -a i386
lxc-create -n centos1 -t centos
```

I also tried some other templates I found over there instead of the one that comes with ubuntu.

Any hints ? Thank you very much.

Comment: don't start and/or don't create lxc centos containers?

Comment: The container is created, it just won't start

Answer (score 0):

How about trying these commands:

```
lxc remote add images 1.2.3.4
lxc launch images:centos/6/i386 test
```

You need to specify where these images will be found you can do this by specifying `images:` to launch.

Comment: Hi Dimitrios, the containers got created, and the centos images where downloaded. Anyway, can you elaborate on the add images command ? What IP should I add ?

Comment: The ip you should use is the `1.2.3.4` this is the one in order to use the oficial lxc container repository.